# Splitting text in a column into multiple rows in python (data wrangling)

Tags: python, split, data-wrangling

```
    channelTitle    video_id      tags
0   Channel1        ojPuGJaiVjE   [tag3, tag4, tag5]
1   Channel1        NdWI3sov93I   [tag1, tag4]
2   Channel1        67PYna-rScE   [tag1, tag2, tag3, tag5]
3   Channel2        lNoDeZzn_4o   NaN
4   Channel3        QJSOGP-nJto   [tag3]
```

Hi all,

I have a pandas dataframe (`video_df`) in python as shown in the table above. May I know how should I split the tags column into multiple rows (depends on how many tags per `video_id`) so that there will be only one tag per row?

The expected output should be something like this:

[image]

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
video_df = video_df.explode('tags', ignore_index=True)

print(video_df)
#   channelTitle     video_id  tags
#0      Channel1  ojPuGJaiVjE  tag3
#1      Channel1  ojPuGJaiVjE  tag4
#2      Channel1  ojPuGJaiVjE  tag5
#3      Channel1  NdWI3sov93I  tag1
#4      Channel1  NdWI3sov93I  tag4
#5      Channel1  67PYna-rScE  tag1
#6      Channel1  67PYna-rScE  tag2
#7      Channel1  67PYna-rScE  tag3
#8      Channel1  67PYna-rScE  tag5
#9      Channel2  lNoDeZzn_4o   NaN
#10     Channel3  QJSOGP-nJto  tag3
```

By default, `DataFrame.explode()` keeps the index value for exploding rows, so you need to specify `ignore_index=True` to reindex.